# Why does cout print the entire String when called wth a character array, and not the pointer to its first element?

Tags: c++, iostream

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    using std::cout; 

    char example1[] = "John";
    int  example2[] = {1,2,3,4};

    cout << example1 << endl;
    cout << example2 << endl;
}
```

The output of the program is as follows -

```
John   
0x7fff50e079b0
```

Why is the first print statement returning the entire string and the second one just the address of the first element?

Comment: Because that's how `cout` was designed. `char` pointers are commonly used as strings in C, and sometimes you want to use them as strings even in C++.

Comment: Both return pointer. << operator probably overloaded for char *. If you want to see the address you can try to print `reinterpret_cast<void*>(example1)`. It will interpret the byte pattern as void * instead of char *.

Comment: @thoron `static_cast` would be more appropriate than `reinterpret_cast`.  But yes, you are correct that `operator<<` is overloaded to treat `char*` as a null-terminated C string, so a cast to `void*` is needed if you want to print the address the pointer holds rather than the data the pointer is pointing at.